# Display image from an external rss feed on wordpress without plugins

Tags: php, images, rss, xml

I am trying to add an external RSS Feed to my wordpress theme.

Displaying the feed content and title was a success. But I don't see any option to display the image from the external feed. I tried reading about it, but most of the answers I found suggests using a plug-in like SimplePie.

I'm wondering if there's another way to do it without plug-ins.